# How to use custom @Query for joining @ElementCollection column in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have a stupid problem and thinking about it for 3 hours. I have @Entity class, for example:

```
private long id;
private Instant startTime;
private Instant lastTime;
private String name;

@ElementCollection
@Builder.Default
private Set<Integer> codes = new HashSet<>();
```

So, Hibernate creates new table with my main class id and codes. It is nice, works correct. 
I have a problem with custom query.. I would like select given codes between given start and endTime. 
It is not difficult to prepare query on my oracle db:

```
select id, startTime, lastTime, name from main_table mt left outer join created_table_codes cd on mt.id = cd.main_table_id
where cd.codes = 12345 and mt.startTime=‘date’ between ‘endDate’ ;
```

Unfortunately, in @Query it is doesn`t work. Hibernate can`t see table created  from my @ElementCollection :(

Do you know how can I get data by @Query - using join and ma @ElementCollection table?

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: That query is supposed to be SQL, or JPQL ? Posting the ACTUAL code would have clarified that

Comment: @JoeTaras - exception is: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: codes

Comment: Yes! You've written cd.codes = 12345 but codes is a hashset. it's no possible